# How could a radiowave controlled cyborg-mutant be possible?

Tags: biology, creature-design, humans, genetic-engineering, mutants

The cells of certain gene edited superhumans were changed to make them produce molecular radiowave receiver inside the cell to allow the superhuman to coordinate the movements and even change genetic code of each cell at the speed of light without the need for pesky and slow nerves, allowing for super fast reaction speeds. These radiowaves would be sent from a specialized, normal sized radiowave transmitter connected to the brain. What could be a molecular radiowave reciever?

Comment: Just FYI. Synapses, the part that slows the signal down the most, does a lot of signal modulation. This is important to keep a body functioning. In addition, how would you separate one radio signal from another in the cell? You might need a brain for each cell to understand what goes where. That being said, do not let reality destroy your story. We're talking about superhumans, so the boundaries of reality need to be pushed back any way.

Comment: The molecule would be tuned to a range of signals, one signal could code to change a base pair, another to contract a muscle etc

Comment: The same way that Superman, Batman, Aquaman, The Flash, the X Men, etc, etc, etc are possible: take for granted that they exist.

Comment: No, go with organic fiber optic cables and chromophore receptors. No external signal disruption. I've used this in stories and RPG's.  https://www.engadget.com/2010-09-18-smu-and-darpa-develop-fiber-optics-for-the-human-nervous-system.html

Comment: Changing genetic code "at the speed of light" is both wildly unrealistic and unnecessary, as any expression of the changed code will occur on the scale of days or weeks, rather than any scale that would require instantaneous genetic changes.

Answer (score 6):

A long enough axon of a nerve cell can potentially act as an antenna that can receive a radio signal. In human body, longest axons are in sciatic nerve where they can exceed one meter (more than 3´4"), so long enough axons do already exist.

On a smaller scale, neurons can be activated with a rapidly changing magnetic field. See [transcranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation). In the end, that is the same idea, although the method is extremely crude compared to what you are asking about. However, the principle is the same, the implementation just needs to be more finely tuned.

Comment: Well, I just want a molecule that can receive radio signals and use the instructions in the radio signals to like do whatever man, not *nerves*

Comment: @GrimmReaper18B Unfortunately molecules are too small for that. See eg. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315915/why-do-we-need-an-antenna-of-size-comparable-to-the-wavelength-for-surface-wave

Comment: Well, I've found a few research papers that say that carbon nanotubes can act as nanoradios

Comment: @GrimmReaper18B Technically that is true, however they are an exception among molecules, since they can be grown as long as antennas need to be.

Comment: No like, carbon nanotubes can receive radio signals while being in the nanometer range

Comment: @GrimmReaper18B Hmmm... can you give a link.

Comment: Carbon nanotubes are only slightly better than other molecules of the body, due to their short length. Their efficiency as radio receivers or transmitters is incredibly poor, and you'd cook a living organism before you got anything useful through them. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3866607/ estimates an achievable bit rate of 1 bit every 3 seconds, and doesn't even go into the problems with multiple transmitters/receivers operating in limited spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

## Use optical nerves instead

As a frame challenge I would suggest optical nerves. Electricity is blisteringly fast, light is faster. An advantage is that you can send different kinds of light through a nerve as well. Where normal nerves often share certain pathways, you can multiply that a thousand fold with the same lightwaves. Include different colours and you can add much more. Normal nerves also have a downtime, increasing the time delay and decreasing signal clarity. Optical nerves can also be two way, increasing signal density even further. Finally, there are signs that electric neurons can interfere with each other. Neurons can activate accidentally if too many neurons close by send signals. Optical neurons do not have this flaw, allowing neurons to be packed more tightly.

All this means that means that the cerebral cortex and other areas can be packed more tightly than the current cerebellum, allowing maybe even 6 times the neurons in many areas of the brain.

Optical nerves are thus faster and can handle more, reducing the neural pathway sizes. Then we need to deal with the synapse. The synapse is an important bit of signal modulation. It is part of an intricate system that help control and conserve your body. If you're hungry you'll generally be more careful with your energy and are more likely to see a food source for example. Just like a real synapse, chemicals can be in the synapse or even axon/dendrite to change the signal. The light passing through can be reduced or otherwise altered to have more or less stimulation of the receiving neuron. Then you've solved one of the most time consuming parts in the nervous system.

This way you'll have thinner neural pathways that have been increased to ludicrous speeds and are more robust, with much more dense and effective neurons in the brain and spine.

Comment: While that doesn’t cover the DNA modulation I do think this is the best answer. DNA modulation would take time to properly execute anyway, its not like a piece of DNA can unfold and be at the right position to be edited by accidentally the exact sequences you wanted in a few seconds flat.

Comment: @Demigan - plus, editing DNA doesn't produce physical expression in any timescale that would _require_ rapid editing.

Answer (score 1):

## Normal Receiver

[image: Image of the robot Bender from Futurama about to chop off the antennae on the top of his head]

*Antennae just like Bender from Futurama*

The simplest way to do this is to have a normal robot, with a metal antennae and wiring, that operates at the speed of light. Replace the chromosomes with tiny little hard-drives containing the *DNA* in binary code. That way it can be rewritten at the speed of electrons, which is almost the speed of light.

Onto your conventional robot, then slap some biological matter on top, like marzipan frosting. Slap on some self-repairing skin and self-growing hair. And a stomach to get energy from food. The biological stuff operates at normal biological speed. of course it does. It's biological stuff, after all.